# On an update statement, what does result = 1 mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Running an update, comes back with

```
 Results
  1
```

Messages

```
(1 row affected)
(0 rows affected)
```

What does the Result = 1 mean?  In all other dbs I run this in, I get a zero, and I thought that was a return code.  I checked @@error and it's 0.  Searched with no joy.

Comment: I don't think it's the number of rows affected.  When I run the code for all other databases with no records, they say results = 0 and same messages - 1 affected, 0 affected

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table you are updating? From what it looks like, if you are getting a resultset out having run an UPDATE statement, could be a trigger that is outputting that value and therefore could be the place the look

Comment: It appears you're running multiple SQL statements in one go - you're getting two " x rows affected" responses. What's the SQL you're running? Is it possible it includes a select statement?

Comment: I run this in multiple dbs, only one has records that match the criteria.  In five dbs, four give me results = 0 and one gives me results = 1 but all say they affected one row.  I do have a trigger, and that is what is giving two messages but I don't think that is affecting the results.  Changing lowercase states to uppercase.  UPDATE users 
SET uscstate = 'PA'
WHERE uscstate = 'pa';  There are no rows that this affects in this DB

Comment: I think beyond this, I can only reiterate the same point. An UPDATE statement alone will just output the messages, not results. Which points to triggers. We cannot know what the output means as the answer to that must be within the trigger(s) (which we cannot see).

Comment: I have a trigger that inserts a history record and only in this particular DB - that must be where the result is coming back 1.  thanks

Comment: No problem. Triggers are often the source of evil ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Results
  1
```

is the result set

```
(1 row affected)
(0 rows affected)
```

is the number of rows affected by current statement/s

**It is not possible for your update to return result set ,unless you are using output clause**

As AdaTheDev points out,you might be having a trigger which can cause below behaviour

> run this in multiple dbs, only one has records that match the criteria. In five dbs, four give me results = 0 and one gives me results = 1 but all say they affected one row.

Comment: I run this in multiple dbs, only one has records that match the criteria.  In five dbs, four give me results = 0 and one gives me results = 1 but all say they affected one row.

Comment: I find the upvotes fascinating.  `update` statements don't usually have a "result set".

Comment: @GordonLinoff:I will highlight that

Comment: I agree with Gordon - updates don't have a result set.  I'll look into the triggers on this table and see if one is using an output statement and check back.

Comment: marking this the answer, but @Gordon_linoff you helped solve it as well, just didn't realize the trigger was doing an insert, which produced the results = 1.  It was a trigger doing insert, not an output statement

Answer (score 0):

The only logical explanation I can come up with is the following.  You have an `update` trigger on your database and it prints out two lines, one with `Results` and one with a number.

The two rows in parentheses mean that you *do* have a trigger.  One refers to the number of rows affected by the trigger and one to the number affected by the overall statement.